# Magento 2 custom login page

Tags: magento2, login

we made a totally custom login page in our Magento 2.2

on form submit, we send the credentials to a custom php page.

In the custom page we get `$_POST['email'] and $_POST['password']`.

How to trigger the magento customer login in this custom PHP script?

We tried some, but without success...

Comment: you cannot create a custom php file you create a custom Module For that

Comment: Have you any suggestion, guide or reference to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code to login with email.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


// Load customer By Email
$customer = $obj->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->loadByEmail('test@example.com');

// Create customer session
$customerSession = $obj->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo "Customer Logged in Successfully";
}else{
    echo "Unable to Login";
}
```

**i hope its work for you.**

Comment: This seems to work but not quite... The script return "Customer Logged in Successfully", but after that I cannot navigate to my account section, I am always redirected to login page...